# Magento 2 : Add Custom Attribute field to Product Form

Tags: magento2, product, product-attribute, uicomponent, magento2.4.2

I need to add the below field into the product form. [Click Here](https://prnt.sc/16osevw)

[image]
**InstallData.php**

```
<?php

namespace Vendorename\ModuleName\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        /* Root category ids */
        //$eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'cms_category_ids');
        // $eavSetup->addAttribute(
        //     \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        //     'cms_category_ids',
        //     [
        //         'type' => 'varchar',
        //         'label' => 'CMS Categories',
        //         'input' => 'select',
        //         'required' => false,
        //         'sort_order' => 90,
        //         'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
        //         'group' => 'Related Content',
        //     ]
        // );

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'related_title');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'related_title',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Title',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Related Content',
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'related_mode');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'related_mode',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Mode',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 20,
                'component' => 'Vendorename_ModuleName/js/form/element/related-mode-list',
                'source' => \Vendorename\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\RelatedModeList::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Related Content',
            ]
        );

        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'related_cms_pages');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'related_cms_pages',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'CMS Pages',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 30,
                'levelsVisibility' => 1,
                'disableLabel' => true,
                'chipsEnabled' => true,
                'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category',
                'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                'source' => \Vendorename\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CMSPageList::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'Related Content',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

Here **related_mode** is a dependent field which hide and show on **related_cms_pages** field. And Form Data not also save and not see in edit mode.

*Please Help me.*

Comment: Your magento version?

Comment: I am using Magento 2.4.2.

Comment: @RohanHapani Have you any idea about it? Please help me to achieve.

Comment: have you tried magento way of creating product attribute from backend?
store->attributes(product)->add new attribute

Comment: But I am creating a module. so attributes are also created when module.

Comment: @AsadUllah we need to use InstallData.php for creating product attribute.

Comment: Do you get that fields value after save response?

Comment: Now I need this type of fields in product form https://prnt.sc/16osevw  and yes now I get save response after save.

Comment: @RohanHapani I need one search select filed and Add js to one simple select field which is depended.

Comment: @RohanHapani have you found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Please Follow Below Steps.

**Step-1:** Create **registration.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName**

```
<?php
 
use Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar;
 
ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'VendoreName_ModuleName', __DIR__);
```

**Step-2:** Create **module.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="VendoreName_ModuleName" setup_version="1.0.1">
        <sequence>
            <module name="Magento_Catalog"/>
        </sequence>
    </module>
</config>
```

**Step-3:** Now we create custom product attributes. Create **InstallData.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Setup**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Setup;
 
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
 
class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    private $eavSetupFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory
    ) {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }
    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
 
        /* Product Custom Title */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_title');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'custom_title',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Title',
                'input' => 'text',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 10,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'custom_content_hide',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
            ]
        );
        /* Product Custom Select Options */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_mode');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'custom_mode',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom Select Option',
                'input' => 'select',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 20,
                'source' => \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CustomModeList::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'group' => 'custom_content_hide',
            ]
        );
        /* Product Custom Multi Select Option */
        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_cms_pages');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
            'custom_cms_pages',
            [
                'type' => 'varchar',
                'label' => 'Custom CMS Pages',
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 30,
                'source' => \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CMSPageList::class,
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'group' => 'custom_content_hide',
            ]
        );
    }
}
```

If you need to add to your existing module then you should use UpgradeData. Don’t forget to change your module version before using UpgradeData.

**Step-4:** Create **CustomModeList.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Config/Source**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;
 
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
 
class CustomModeList extends AbstractSource
{
 
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $options = [];
        $options[] = (__('CMS Page HIDE'));
        $options[] = (__('CMS Page SHOW'));
        return $options;
    }
 
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }
 
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }
 
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getOptions();
    }
}
```

**Step-5:** Create **CMSPageList.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Model/Config/Source**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source;
 
use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource;
 
class CMSPageList extends AbstractSource
{
    protected $_userFactory;
    protected $pageFactory;
 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepositoryInterface,
        \Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder
    ) {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->pageRepositoryInterface = $pageRepositoryInterface;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }
 
    public function getOptionArray()
    {
        $searchCriteria = $searchCriteria = $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->create();
        $pages = $this->pageRepositoryInterface->getList($searchCriteria)->getItems();
        $options = [];
        foreach ($pages as $page) {
            $pageData = $this->pageFactory->create();
            $categoryIds = $pageData->load($page->getId());
            $options[$page->getId()] = $page->getTitle();
 
        }
        return $options;
    }
 
    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        $res = $this->getOptions();
        array_unshift($res, ['value' => '', 'label' => '']);
        return $res;
    }
 
    public function getOptions()
    {
        $res = [];
        foreach ($this->getOptionArray() as $index => $value) {
            $res[] = ['value' => $index, 'label' => $value];
        }
        return $res;
    }
 
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return $this->getOptions();
    }
}
```

**After creating and adding the above files run Magento 2 commands**

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**Now We modify the custom fieldset and field into Product From using Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool.**

**Step-6:** Create **di.xml** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/etc/adminhtml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
 
    <virtualType name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\Pool" type="Magento\Ui\DataProvider\Modifier\Pool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="modifiers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="newFields" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="class" xsi:type="string">VendoreName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\CustomContent</item>
                    <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">40</item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType> 
</config>
```

**Step-7:** Create **CustomContent.php** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/Ui/DataProvider/Product/Form/Modifier**

```
<?php
 
namespace VendoreName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier;
 
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier\AbstractModifier;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\DataType\Text;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Input;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\MultiSelect;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Element\Select;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Field;
use Magento\Ui\Component\Form\Fieldset;
 
class CustomContent extends AbstractModifier
{
    private $locator;
    private $modeList;
    private $pageList;
    private $cacheManager;
 
    public function __construct(
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CustomModeList $modeList,
        \VendoreName\ModuleName\Model\Config\Source\CMSPageList $pageList,
        LocatorInterface $locator
    ) {
        $this->modeList = $modeList;
        $this->pageList = $pageList;
        $this->locator = $locator;
    }
 
    public function modifyMeta(array $meta)
    {
        $meta = array_replace_recursive(
            $meta,
            [
                'custom_content' => [
                    'arguments' => [
                        'data' => [
                            'config' => [
                                'label' => __('Custom Content'),
                                'componentType' => Fieldset::NAME,
                                'dataScope' => 'data.product',
                                'collapsible' => true,
                                'sortOrder' => 5,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'children' => [
                        'custom_title' => $this->getCustomTitle(),
                        'custom_mode' => $this->getCustomMode(),
                        'custom_cms_pages' => $this->getCustomCmsPages(),
                    ],
                ],
            ]
        );
        /* Hide Custom Content Attributes */
        if (isset($meta['custom-content-hide'])) {
            unset($meta['custom-content-hide']);
        }
        return $meta;
    }
 
    public function getCustomTitle()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Custom Title'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Input::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'custom_title',
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => 10,
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
 
    public function getCustomMode()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Custom Mode Options'),
                        'component' => 'VendoreName_ModuleName/js/form/element/custom-mode-list',
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'formElement' => Select::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'custom_mode',
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => 20,
                        'options' => $this->getCustomModeOptions(),
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
 
    public function getCustomCmsPages()
    {
        return [
            'arguments' => [
                'data' => [
                    'config' => [
                        'label' => __('Custom CMS Pages'),
                        'componentType' => Field::NAME,
                        'component' => 'Magento_Catalog/js/components/new-category',
                        'elementTmpl' => 'ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select',
                        'levelsVisibility' => 1,
                        'disableLabel' => true,
                        'formElement' => MultiSelect::NAME,
                        'dataScope' => 'custom_cms_pages',
                        'chipsEnabled' => true,
                        'dataType' => Text::NAME,
                        'sortOrder' => 30,
                        'required' => 1,
                        'options' => $this->getCustomCmsOptions(),
                        'validation' => ['required-entry' => 1],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
        ];
    }
 
    public function getCustomModeOptions()
    {
        return $this->modeList->toOptionArray();
    }
 
    public function getCustomCmsOptions()
    {
        return $this->pageList->toOptionArray();
    }
 
    public function modifyData(array $data)
    {
        $product = $this->locator->getProduct();
        $productId = (int) $product->getId();
        $cmsPages = [];
        $cmsCategoryIds = '';
        if ($product->getCustomCmsPages()) {
            $cmsPages = array_map('intval', explode(',', $product->getCustomCmsPages()));
        }
        if ($product->getCmsCategoryIds()) {
            $cmsCategoryIds = $product->getCmsCategoryIds();
        }
 
        $data = array_replace_recursive(
            $data, [
                $productId => [
                    'product' => [
                        'custom_title' => $product->getCustomTitle(),
                        'custom_mode' => $product->getCustomMode(),
                        'custom_cms_pages' => $cmsPages,
                    ],
                ],
            ]);
        return $data;
    }
}
```

**Step-8:** Create **custom-mode-list.js** at **app/code/VendoreName/ModuleName/view/adminhtml/web/js/form/element**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'uiRegistry',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select'
], function ($, _, uiRegistry, select) {
    'use strict';
    return select.extend({
        initialize: function (){
            this._super();
            var customMode = this._super().initialValue;
            setTimeout(function () {
                var customCMSPages = uiRegistry.get('index = custom_cms_pages');
                    if (customMode == 1) {
                        customCMSPages.show();
                    } else{
                        customCMSPages.hide();
                    }
 
            }, 1000);
            return this;
        },
 
        /**
         * On value change handler.
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        onUpdate: function (value) {
            this.fieldDepend(value);
            return this._super();
        },
 
        /**
         * Update field dependency
         *
         * @param {String} value
         */
        fieldDepend: function (value) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                var customCMSPages = uiRegistry.get('index = custom_cms_pages');
                if (value == 1) {
                    customCMSPages.show();
                } else {
                    customCMSPages.hide();
                }
            }, 500);
            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

Now please run the **PHP bin/Magento cache:clean** command and refresh the product form. You can see custom fieldset and fields in product form.

> You can also modify the existing form fieldset and field. In CustomContent.php at **VendoreName\ModuleName\Ui\DataProvider\Product\Form\Modifier** file, there are two main methods.

**modifyMeta($meta):** This method allows you to add and modify fieldset and fields in Product Form. Here the whole product goes into $meta variable, which variable we use for adding and modifying Product Form.

**modifyData($data):** This method allows you to save and modifying form Data. In this method, Magento\Catalog\Model\Locator\LocatorInterface class provides your current product data by using $this->locator->getProduct() method which helps you to get and show product data.

[image]

***I Hope This Helps You.***