# Load attribute depends upon previous selected attribute

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, product-page

We are having two dropdown attributes on product level Brand and Model. Consider Brand are Mahindra,Kia,Hyundai and Model
having Mahnidra Bolero, Mahindra Scorpio,Kia Sonet, Kia EV6, Hyundai i20, Hyundai Venue.
Our requirement is that if we have selected Mahindra as a Brand then from model it should show only Mahnidra Bolero, Mahindra Scorpio. This functionality we are to implement on product add and product edit page. Please suggest if anyone have any answer.

Comment: Please check this link.: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/344609/82670
You need to update JS. also this helps you : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/304617/82670

You can combine both solution in one.

Comment: @Msquare thanks for replying but this will not work bcz we are adding this on product level we are not creating any filed here via listing.. On products attribute only we have to perform this onchange functionality.

Comment: I believe default Magento has this features  (Configurable product). You can check their code and make it yours.

Comment: @HoangHieu can you guide more on your answer.